# How to fix "Error: dispatch failure" when uploading to AWS Timestream using Rust?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, amazon-timestream

So I'm trying to write a program that is able to upload data to AWS Timestream, but the problem is that I continue to get "Error: dispatch failure" when trying to upload records. My function is defined as follows:

```
pub async fn upload() {
        let region = Region::new("us-east-1");
        let config = SdkConfig::builder().region(region).build();
        let client = AWSClient::new(&config);

        let common_attributes = Record::builder()
            .measure_name("cpu_usage")
            .dimensions(Dimension::builder().name("host").value("host1").build())
            .build();

        let new_record = Record::builder()
            .measure_name("cpu_usage")
            .measure_value("13.5")
            .time(chrono::Utc::now().to_rfc3339())
            .dimensions(Dimension::builder().name("host").value("host1").build())
            .build();

        let _request = client
            .write_records()
            .database_name("sampleDB")
            .table_name("sampleTB")
            .common_attributes(common_attributes)
            .records(new_record)
            .send()
            .await
            .unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
                panic!("Error sending data to timestream");
            });
}
```

I am able to get up to the creation of the new_record, but executing client.write_records() returns "Error: dispatch failure". Does anyone know what I should do to make it work? The crates I am using are: aws_config, aws_sdk_timestreamwrite, and aws_types.